# Porque me da Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';?

Tags: php, html, sql, web, sintaxis

```
 <?php
extract($_POST);
include("database.php");
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM register where Email='$email'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
{
    echo "Email Id Already Exists"; 
    exit;
}
else(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="upload/";
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO register(First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password, File ) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', 'md5($pass)', '$final_file')";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
        header ("Location: login.php?status=success");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error.Please try again";
    }
}
```

error linea 12, y no tengo idea de porque.Es un formulario de registro, cuando intento registrarme me dice Porque me da Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';

Ya no si es que no tengo actualizado el php o que

Comment: Ese código está totalmente abierto a inyección sql. Eso puede ser una puerta abierta a tu base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes aquí, que hay un error de sintaxis grave:

```
else(isset($_POST['save']))
```

Seguramente, el código correcto sea este y se te olvidó poner el if para la condición que estabas planteando:

```
else 
if(isset($_POST['save']))
```